# How can I add a caption/text to my csExDropDownList Combobox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, combobox, label

I'm currently trying to create a combobox that has a "caption". By caption I mean the text that you see when you haven't clicked on it yet or if you are choosing an option.

Before I added the `csExDropDownList` it worked fine, but I wanted it to be `ReadOnly`. Now when I edit the `Text` property, it instantly gets deleted. I thought about using a `TLabel` in front of the combobox and making it dissapear the moment I chose a dropdown, but the `TLabel` is always in the background. I also tried with the `TStaticText` component, but that leaves a different colored background in front of the combobox which looks bad.

If I was unable to explain with words what I'm trying to edit/wanted to add a text to, this is what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to my problem. I added a third dropdown with the index of 0. Now in properties I put the `ItemIndex` to 0 which means that it will be displayed similar to the `Text` property. When I interact with either QuickSort or InsertSort I delete Index 0.

My code looks like this:

```
procedure TSorterForm.AlgorithmCbxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
     if (AlgorithmCbx.Text <> 'Choose Algorithm...') and not IsAlgorithmSelected then begin
       AlgorithmCbx.Items.Delete(0);
       IsAlgorithmSelected:= true;
     end;
end;
```

Obviously not perfect so it'd be great if you could tell me how to improve this.